# How to build a good foundation shell to load items

Tags: php, html, css, rest

I am trying to building an application that can load different components. The application itself is like a shell and it contains 6 components. Below is the basic structure. I am trying to decides what's the best practice to load the components.

I will use php as my service side language, REST and might create a manifest file to load the contents . The components include html, flash, video…etc.

my current structure

```
<section class='container part1'>
    <div>
          componets…..

    </div>
</section>

<section class='container part2"'>
    <div>
            componets…..

    </div>
</section>

<section class='container part3'>
    <div>
             componets…..
    </div>
</section>

<section class='container part4'>
    <div>
           componets…..

    </div>
</section>

…more
```

I was hoping you guys can give me a good tips to build the foundation.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement some type of 'widget' system. Most frameworks out there have this basic idea built in, like code igniter, laravel, etc.